# jQuery Drag 'n Drop an image from a button?

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to set up jQuery UI's Draggable widget so that I can essentially drag an image "out of" a button? As if the button contains infinite objects that are invisible, and become real elements that can be dropped into another box when dragging from the button?

I have a button that, when pressed, appends a new DIV to a place in my page. Instead of clicking the button, it'd be neat to allow users to drag objects from the button into the stage.

Possible? Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible for you to please share a jsfiddle of it?

Comment: Thanks, @ajc. I posted an answer to my own question...apparently I had searched but looked over something.

Answer (score 0):

After looking into this a bit further, it turns out that the missing link here was jQuery UI's Droppable widget. If you make use of the "drop" argument, you can tell the plugin what to drop instead of the element you're dragging.

http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop

Answer (score 0):

I guess the big picture to solve this problem can be like this:

1. create a drag-over object when the button was dragged so that your user see the object while moving their mouse.
2. Insert the object to your document when it is dropped.

A running example can be found at: 
[A running example of drag-drop](http://jsfiddle.net/RZx6E/9/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#div_dragIcon").draggable({
      helper: "clone"
  });

$("#divCanvas").droppable({
    drop: function (e, ui) {
        $(this).append(ui.helper.clone());
    }
});
```

Hope that is helpful.